# How to get root or specified node by name via xpath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Need to get some node specified by name. For example how it should look for node 'command' or root node?

Here's what I wrote

```
        $xpath = "/ns0:StandardBusinessDocument/eanucc:message/eanucc:transaction/command";
        $xpath .= "/eanucc:documentCommand/documentCommandOperand/ns1:catalogueItemNotification/catalogueItem";
        $xpath .= "/catalogueItemChildItemLink/catalogueItem/catalogueItemChildItemLink/catalogueItem/tradeItem";
        $xpath .= "/tradeItemIdentification/gtin[.='$gtin']/";
```

where `$gtin = 00000075032814`

Here's what I got

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 00000075032814
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 00000075032814
        )

)
```

UPD: Thing is i can get node like this

```
"[catalogueItem/tradeItem/tradeItemIdentification/gtin[.='$gtin']]"
```

But if I'm going upper - there are two more nodes 'catalogueItem' and I'm getting an xpath error.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add the programming language as a tag and show a complete sample of the code that can be used to reproduce your problem. Also show the input XML document and say what exactly you expect as the result. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root node: `/*`

Nodes by name: `//*[local-name() = 'command']` or `//command` (assuming they are in the correct XML namespace)

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name